# SymmetricDS: No enum constant org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.transform.ColumnPolicy.specified

Tags: symmetricds

I'm doing multi-homing SymmetricDS with 2 nodes (server and client) and single MySQL database, and I do transformation table and column, but at client node appear an error "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.jumpmind.symmetric.io.data.transform.ColumnPolicy.specified".

I (un)delete column_policy from sym_transform_table and nothing happened. What's wrong?

Comment: what's the content of your `SYM_TRANSFORM_COLUMN` table?

Comment: `insert into sym_transform_column
(transform_id, include_on, source_column_name, target_column_name, pk, transform_type, create_time, last_update_by, last_update_time)
values
('peserta_from_staging', '*', 'id', 'id', 1, 'copy', current_timestamp, 'YosuaLB', current_timestamp),
('peserta_from_staging', '*', 'name', 'name', 0, 'copy', current_timestamp, 'YosuaLB', current_timestamp),
('peserta_from_appname', '*', 'id', 'id', 1, 'copy', current_timestamp, 'YosuaLB', current_timestamp),
('peserta_from_appname', '*', 'name', 'name', 0, 'copy', current_timestamp, 'YosuaLB', current_timestamp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, I should make column_policy at SYM_TRANSFORM_TABLE in UPPERCASE MODE. And also apply in other enum.

Answer (score 1):

this is going to fix the problem:

```
update sym_transform_table
set column_policy = 'SPECIFIED'
where column_policy = 'specified';
commit;
```